# Incoming Grants: CiviGrant or CiviCase?

Tags: civicase, civigrant

A new non-profit is asking which component is best for tracking incoming grants, and tracking them at a more detailed level (with activities, maybe even tying the final incoming contribution to the grant).

I saw the older blog post about CiviGrant vs CiviCase, and understand the concepts there.  But I'd like to get a feel for what most folks use these days for this type of incoming grant tracking.

It seems to me that CiviGrant is rather basic in design. It just tracks the most basic parts of a grant: its status, type, amounts, etc. It doesn't necessarily track ongoing activities at the grant level (each time there is communication or meetings about the grant, and so on). It also doesn't tie to a contribution, it seems.

CiviCase, on the other hand, is rather complex in its structure as it has workflows. It almost does more than what one might want for grant tracking. But it seems to allow for activities and maybe even contributions tied to the grant.

So it's a toss up between simplicity vs deeper tracking. What do people find most useful for incoming grant tracking?  Do you all use CiviGrant and add activity types (but not sure how it would link to the grant itself)? Or do you use CiviCase and create a more basic workflow?

Appreciate any thoughts you all might have!

Answer (score 3):

I find that this is really dependent on the client's needs.  If all they need is a list of grants they applied for, I might use neither - and just use activities.  If they need to track upcoming deadlines for applications, deliverables, statuses, etc., then CiviCase is a better fit.

Comment: Concur with Jon. Custom Activity Types can go along way by themselves. Weaving them together in to a Case might be helpful if you have a lot of grant tracking and want to set up a system that copes with more convuluted or nuanced workflows